# Can I access the TaskToken from a Map state with ItemSelector where the iteration step uses lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am using AWS step function to iterate over a list in an input document where for each iteration, I need to invoke an external service. So I want to iterate over each item and run a step using `lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken` and pass the `TaskToken` into the execution of each iteration.

The problem I'm running into is how to use both an `ItemSelector` at the Map state level but also inject the `TaskToken` during the internal step. I need to use an `ItemSelector` because **I want each item to also contain information from the input to Map state**. The [AWS Docs state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-itemselector.html):

> The ItemSelector field replaces the Parameters field within the Map state. If you use the Parameters field in your Map state definitions to create custom input, we highly recommend that you replace them with ItemSelector.

But [they also say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html):

> During an execution, the context object is populated with relevant data for the Parameters field from where it is accessed. The value for a Task field is null if the Parameters field is outside of a task state.

These two statements seem to imply that what I'm trying to do is impossible.

So, what I want is something like:

```
{
  "StartAt": "ExampleMapState",
  "States": {
    "ExampleMapState": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.items",
      "ItemSelector": {
        "dynamic.$": "$.dynamic",
        "ContextIndex.$": "$$.Map.Item.Index",
        "ContextValue.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
      },
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "TestPass",
        "States": {
          "TestPass": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:echo-lambda",
              "Payload": {
                "item.$": "$",
                "token.$": "$$.Task.Token"
              }
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work because the `ItemSelector` overrides the `Payload` of the internal `TestPass` state. Is there a way to get this to work?

---

ETA: I figured I would try putting $$.Task.Token in ItemSelector just in case it would magically work but it ended up throwing an error because $$.Task does not exist in the context object at that level.

Example with this (invalid) configuration:

```
{
    "StartAt": "ExampleMapState",
    "States": {
      "ExampleMapState": {
        "Type": "Map",
        "ItemsPath": "$.items",
        "ItemSelector": {
          "dynamic.$": "$.dynamic",
          "ContextIndex.$": "$$.Map.Item.Index",
          "ContextValue.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
          "token.$": "$$.Task.Token"
        },
        "ItemProcessor": {
          "ProcessorConfig": {
            "Mode": "INLINE"
          },
          "StartAt": "TestPass",
          "States": {
            "TestPass": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Parameters": {
                "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:echo-lambda"
              },
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        "End": true
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research I don't think what I'm trying to do is possible. What I ended up implementing is a workaround. I modified the function providing input to this step function to put the `dynamic` info that I needed into every item in the list I am iterating over. So my step function definition now looks something like this

```
{
  "StartAt": "ExampleMapState",
  "States": {
    "ExampleMapState": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.items",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "TestPass",
        "States": {
          "TestPass": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:echo-lambda",
              "Payload": {
                "item.$": "$",
                "token.$": "$$.Task.Token"
              }
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

And an example input to this step function looks like:

```
{
    "dynamic": "info",
    "items": [
        {
            "dynamic": "info",
            "resize": "true",
            "format": "jpg"
        },
        {
            "dynamic": "info",
            "resize": "false",
            "format": "png"
        },
        {
            "dynamic": "info",
            "resize": "true",
            "format": "jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's not great because I have to repeat info into every item ahead of time but it works.

Comment: so does this require each task iteration in the `map` to receive the task token successfully before the `map` is completed? In this way, you are generating a separate task token for each iteration in the `map`, or is it a single task token?

Comment: Yes, this example generates a unique task token for each iteration of the map.